# Updater Error: Destination dir is not writeable

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-updater

EE 2.9.2 Updater 3.2.15

After uploading a file and starting the action queue, I get this error

"LOCAL: The destination dir is not writeable:"

There is nothing after the last colon to explain in more detail. Updater's test settings says FAILED for all 25 tests.

I have checked the permissions and ownership of all the files. I have had Nexcess check the permissions and ownership of the files. They reviewed [your common errors page](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/common-errors/) They wrote…

> I would recommend contacting the developer directly for more information if possible, as the files are all owned by your user/group and as he states in his bottom portion of his FAQ since it's a single user environment for this account, the permissions are set correctly with 2755 and 0644 which is standard for accounts such as this on shared environments for security reasons.

Comment: Perhaps the problem could be inside the .htaccess file, a command protect the folder to be written.

Comment: Good idea. But the only redirect we have is to hide the index.php.

Comment: or perhaps could not be the .htaccess in your site root, but an .htaccess file inside your folder plugins.

Comment: Very interesting idea. I checked and I don't see .htaccess in the add-on directories. I checked the 6 directories Updater wants to access and no htaccess there either.

Comment: Suddenly it is working. I changed the permissions on the /themes/third_party and Updater now says the directories 'passed'. I set the permissions back and it still works. And I can use Updater. I wish I understood this one better.

Comment: Nice to know it's working ! Sometimes a small problem setting like this could Can make us waste much time.